# Transmission rate monitoring tool for lots of interfaces and sort by usage

Tags: linux, bandwidth

What tool can I use to easily monitor the transmission rate in a short recent time window of all interfaces and sort them by traffic usage.

I have tried `iptraf-ng` which works great except you can't sort in General interfaces statistics.

Comment: bandwidth is a property of a link. Do you mean data rate in a short, current time window?

Comment: Yes current data rate over a short period